# Guice: Getting Dependencies inside provides method

Tags: scala, guice

I am writing a Guice Module and in that module I have a provides method.

```
class FooModule extends ScalaModule {
    @Provides
    @Singleton
    def providesFoo() : Foo = {
        new Foo()
    }
}
```

The problem is that the constructor of `new Foo` takes a Type Bar as parameter.

I want to know how do I ask guice to give me an instance of Bar so that I can do a new on Foo in the Module

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Request those parameters by specifying them as method parameters. From the [Provides method wiki documentation](https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/ProvidesMethods):

> Dependencies can be passed in as parameters to the method. The injector will exercise the bindings for each of these before invoking the method.

So:

```
@Provides
@Singleton
def providesFoo(val bar : Bar) : Foo = {
    new Foo(bar)
}
```